# Systemd unit file to call master script

Tags: linux, systemd, tibco, rhel7

I am creating a system unit file for RHEL7 that looks like:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/tibco/scripts/tibco-upstart.sh
```

And this is owned by a UserA,and they can add all these scripts that they want to add.
`/opt/tibco/scripts/tibco-upstart.sh` calls other scripts that APP TEAM can add as they like.
For instance :`/opt/tibco/scripts/tibco-upstart.sh` looks like

```
/tibco/scripts/startagents.sh
/tibco/scripts/startkafka.sh
/tibco/scripts/startjvms.sh
```

Is it possible that a Unit file can work like this? I tried `forking` and `oneshot` but the processes are not starting as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your system unit has no other relevant directives, *systemd* will expect your startup script to keep running forever as a daemon; otherwise *systemd* will respawn it over and over again.

If your intention is to run the startup script once, add the directives

```
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=Yes
```

into the *Service* section.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.